# how to set text/plain content-type in api gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-api-gateway, api-gateway

I have an api gateway that is pointed to s3 and it reads the document and sends back the contents, about 5 paragraphs.  It works great, however the content-type on the response is binary\octet-stream.  For app integration it would be better if this was text\plain as it is just plain text. I have tried to set this as a parameter on the request with response-content-type.  I have also tried to map it within the api gateway integration response.  If I leave off the Content-Type mapping I get application/json instead.  I've followed the docs here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/integrating-api-with-aws-services-s3.html

Answer (score 0):

The Content-Type on the s3 object was set to binary/octet-stream.  Set this to text/plain and works great now!